# Como pasar de una lista de diccionarios a un set /lista de compras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, condiciones, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy con un ejercicio que realmente me sobrepasa. Tengo que la siguiente lista de diccionarios retornar un set con los productos que estan al menos el 50% o las boletas...

```
 boletas = [
{
'fecha_compra' : '29-05-22', 
'precio' : 12000, 
'productos' : {'Chocolate': 1, 'Mantequilla': 1, 'Huevos': 12, 'Pan' : 1} 
},
{
'fecha_compra' : '31-05-22', 
'precio' : 2400, 
'productos' : {'Pan': 1, 'Leche' : 2} 
}, 
{
'fecha_compra' : '01-06-22', 
'precio' : 3000, 
'productos' : {'Mantequilla': 2, 'Azucar' : 1} 
} 
]
```

deberás definir la función productos_frecuentes(boletas), la cuál recibe como parámetro una lista de boletas en el formato anterior. La función deberá retornar un set con aquellos productos que estén en al menos el 50% de las boletas, es decir, aquellos productos que se compraron en la mitad de todas las compras o más. Para el ejemplo anterior, este set deberá contener: `{'Pan', 'Mantequilla'}`

Estoy intentando algunas cosas pero la verdad que desorientado de como hacerlo ...

```
for k in boletas: 
    mis_productos = k['productos'] 
    esta_en_este_mes= len(boletas) 
    promedio_boletas=esta_en_este_mes/2

for k in mis_productos:
    if k >= promedio_boletas: 
    print(mis_productos)
```

Comment: No quiero me me lo resuelvan... si por favor explicarme que pasos deberia seguir u cualqwuier orientacion es bienvenida . Gracias !!! Claramente soy nuevo en esto .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boletas = [{
    'fecha_compra' : '29-05-22', 
    'precio' : 12000, 
    'productos' : {'Chocolate': 1, 'Mantequilla': 1, 'Huevos': 12, 'Pan' : 1} 
}, {
    'fecha_compra' : '31-05-22', 
    'precio' : 2400, 
    'productos' : {'Pan': 1, 'Leche' : 2} 
}, {
    'fecha_compra' : '01-06-22', 
    'precio' : 3000, 
    'productos' : {'Mantequilla': 2, 'Azucar' : 1} 
}]  

# definimos el metodo que recibirá una lista de boletas y retornará un set de productos frecuentes
def productos_frecuentes(boletas):
    productos = {}
    num_boletas = len(boletas)

    # Contar la frecuencia de cada producto en las boletas
    # Para esto debemos recorrer todas las boletas y todos los productos de cada boleta
    # almacenando en "productos" el contador de cada producto
    for boleta in boletas:
        # aqui es donde temos que recorrer los productos por boleta actual y contarlos.
        for producto in boleta['productos']:
            if producto in productos:
                productos[producto] += 1
            else:
                productos[producto] = 1


    # Obtener los productos que cumplen con el criterio de frecuencia
    # declaramos el set de productos frecuentes como lo indica el enunciado
    productos_frecuentes = set()
    for producto, frecuencia in productos.items():
        # aplicamos el criterio de frecuencia para agregar el producto al set
        if frecuencia >= num_boletas / 2:
            productos_frecuentes.add(producto)

    # retornamos el set de productos frecuentes
    return productos_frecuentes

# probamos la ejecución del método
print(productos_frecuentes(boletas))
```

Te invito a leer los comentarios y entender la lógica, además de jugar con el código para conseguir resultados similares aplicando métodos distintos.

Comment: Hola Isaac. Gracias ! Ahora voy a ver todo. Si podes recomendarme libro/ lecturas de python... seria buenísimo... Estoy recién animándome a  meterme en este mundo y me gusta ... no tengo una bibliografia a seguir ...un lugar para tomar de base . Estoy con 2da ed python ... pero no se ....Gracias . Ahora me meto de lleno en el ejercicio.

Comment: En resumen, el código contabiliza cuántas compras incluyeron cada producto. Para eso utiliza un diccionario. De esta forma es más fácil saber si un producto cumple la condición. Por último haces la verificación para cada producto.

Comment: @Ivan, recuerda poner la pregunta como resulta.

Comment: Hola . perdon . tema resuelto . No se si en algun lugar se cambia el estado de la pregunta a RESUELTO.

Comment: @Ivan Puedes utilizar la guia para ello: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Perfecto .  Gracias